# How to get list of reports that use the dataset?

Tags: powerbi

I'm looking at the dataset Lineage view and I can see only reports I have created.

How to get list of all reports that use the dataset?

Answer (score 0):

2 ways

1)

- you can check in the service (app.powerbi.com)
- go to settings/admin portal/usage metrics/data sets
- click the dataset and it'll show the reports that use the dataset

2. 

- use Power Bi Helper by RADACAD [enter link description here](https://radacad.com/power-bi-helper)
- open poer bi helper, then click on power bi file tab
- browse button/select the pbix file and load it
- after it's loaded, you can see the relationship between different objects in the objects tab.  You can filter to show only reports, datasets, data sources, etc.

Personally, I really like the RADACAD tool and have used it to reduce columns in reports.  It has a ton of functionality and is free to use.